# "insmod: invalid module format" when trying to use operaFS

Tags: linux, kernel, insmod

I want to build and install the Linux filesystem driver [OperaFS](https://github.com/gameblabla/operafs/blob/master/INSTALL). After compiling the source codes, "insmod" shows the error message "module invalid format", although I did download the package "linux-source", so I expect that the source is the source of my currently used kernel.

I did following so far:

```
$ uname -a
Linux debianstretch 4.9.0-3-686-pae #1 SMP Debian 4.9.30-2+deb9u2 (2017-06-26) i686 GNU/Linux

$ sudo su
$ aptitude update
$ aptitude upgrade (so I have the latest kernel now)
$ aptitude install linux-source libssl-dev
$ cd /usr/src
$ tar xf linux-source-4.9.tar.xz
$ cd linux-source-4.9
$ make oldconfig && make prepare
$ make scripts

Download ZIP from github.com/gameblabla/operafs ... and unzip ...
$ cd ~/Downloads/operafs
$ sudo su
$ make -C /usr/src/linux-source-4.9/ M=$PWD modules
$ make -C /usr/src/linux-source-4.9/ M=$PWD modules_install
$ modinfo operafs.ko
filename:     ...
license:      GPLv2
author:       Serge van den Boom
description:  3DO 'Opera' filesystem support
depends:
vermagic:     4.9.30 SMP mod_unload modversions 686
$ insmod operafs.ko
insmod: ERROR: could not insert module operafs.ko: Invalid module format
$ modprobe operafs
modprobe: FATAL: Module operafs not found in directory /lib/modules/4.9.0-3-686-pae
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you try running `depmod` as root after `modules_install`?

Comment: @rodrigo No, I didn't try that. Now, I tried to run "depmod" (without arguments?). It returns with exitcode 0, but insmod and modprobe still fail.

Comment: And anything interesting in `dmesg`?

Comment: @rodrigo Thanks for that hint! Indeed there is an error reported each time I try insmod: "operafs: no symbol version for module_layout". I am trying to find out what that means now.

Comment: Glad to help. Take a look at the options in `man depmod` about symbols and symbol versions, maybe they will help.